# Plugin Error: FindBugs-IDEA -> How can I remove it?

Tags: android-studio

since some weeks Android Studio shows me "Plugin Error" info. But I can't remove this plugin. I don't see it in the plugin list.

How can I remove it?

[image: Plugin Error]

Answer (score 0):

Look for the configuration files directory. On Linux you would have something like this

```
~/.local/share/Google/AndroidStudio4.1
```

You should find there a directory named

```
FindBugs-IDEA-1.0.1
```

Replace versions numbers with your own, delete the directory or JAR file.